# How to upgrade ubuntu with security fixes without updating PHP with new major version?

Tags: ubuntu, php, apt, ubuntu-16.04

On my web servers I run ubuntu 16.04 with php7.2. I would like to be able to run periodically cron task to install system security fixes and updates (something like `apt-get upgrade`) but I don't want this process to replace php7.2 with newer php versions (eg: php7.4). I would like to patch php7.2 with new minor versions though (something like `apt-get install --only-upgrade php7.2`).

How can I do so ?

Thanx in advance

Comment: Where did you get php 7.2 from? Ubuntu 16.04 comes with php 7.0 so the newer version of php must have been installed from a PPA.

Comment: @Bert you mean if I actually used a ppa like "ondrej/php", `apt-get upgrade` won't update php7.2 ?

Answer (score 3):

You can prevent a package from being upgraded using `apt-mark`. Simply run:

`sudo apt-mark hold php7.2`

This can be reversed by unholding the package:

`sudo apt-mark unhold php7.2`

You can also view your held packages by running:

`apt-mark showhold`

Once a package is held, it will not be upgraded when running `apt dist-upgrade` and other upgrade commands.

This solution will not upgrade the package at all, not even minor versions. I believe you will have to manually unhold the package, then run `sudo apt install php7.2` in order to get minor upgrade releases.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This worked for me, I used `sudo apt-mark hold php7.4*` for preventing me system to upgrade to php7.4 (extensions included) :)